# How to have nested libraries? Confused about dune etc

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I have an OCaml project using `dune`

Following advice in basic tutorials I have a dir structure like:

```
bin/
    cli.ml
    dune
lib/
    dune
    ...
    <various>.ml
```

The number of files in my `lib` dir is growing and I would like to have another level of namespacing.

I want sub dirs like:

```
lib/
    utils/
        dune
        ...
        <various>.ml
    some_other_domain/
        dune
        ...
        <various>.ml
    dune
    ...
    <various>.ml
```

And I want to be able to open them like `Lib.Utils.Whatever`

I assume this must be possible?

I tried making a `dune` file under `lib/utils` like:

```lisp
(library
  (name utils)
  (libraries ...))
```

...but `open Lib.Utils.Whatever` doesn't seem to work.

I found the [`subdir` stanza](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#subdir) ...but if I add that to `lib/dune` and define `utils` as a subdir `library` then I don't get the namespacing... I have to `open Utils` rather than `open Lib.Utils`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually a bit strange to call them "nested libraries" since you want to call them with `Lib.Utils.Whatever`. `Utils`, here, is a sub-module of `Lib`. Here's what I was able to do if it can help you:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── cli.ml
│   └── dune
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
│   ├── lib.ml
│   ├── suba
│   │   └── suba.ml
│   └── subb
│       └── subb.ml
```

With

`bin/cli.ml`

```ml
let () =
  Lib.Suba.a ();
  Lib.Subb.b ()
```

`bin/dune`

```ml
(executable
 (name cli)
 (libraries lib)
)
```

`lib/dune`

```ml
(include_subdirs unqualified)

(library
 (name lib)
  (modules suba subb)
)
```

(If you include your modules like this, you'll have to use them with these exact names, another way of gaining control is to add the following file and remove the `(modules suba subb)` line:

`lib/lib.ml`

```ml
(* here you can give the name you want -- say A -- and use it in bin with Lib.A *)
module Suba = Suba
module Subb = Subb
```

(to summarise:

- either your `dune` file is containing `(modules suba subb)`

  - if sub-directory is containing multiple files, you need to put all the files you're using inside your `(modules ...)` stanza or the compiler won't be able to use them
- or a `lib.ml` file where each module you want to export should be included with `module MyName = AModule` (and only the ones you want to export)

  - with this solution, the modules you don't want to export don't need to be explicitly included in the `lib.ml` file, the compiler will use them if needed
    )

`sub{a|b}/{a|b}.ml`

```ml
let {a|b} () = Format.eprintf "{A|B}@."
```

`suba.ml` and `subb.ml` are used as sub-modules of `lib` and can be used with `Lib.Suba.a()` as you can see in `cli.ml`

---

Notice that this forbids you from giving the exact same name to two files since the directories will all be flatten in the parent directory so you can't have something like:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── cli.ml
│   └── dune
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
│   ├── lib.ml
│   ├── suba
│   │   └── lib.ml
│   └── subb
│       └── lib.ml
```

because `(include_subdirs unqualified)` will make it look like

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── cli.ml
│   └── dune
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── dune
│   ├── lib.ml
│   ├── lib.ml
|   └── lib.ml
```

and `dune` won't be able to know which `lib.ml` file to use.

---

[EDIT] If you want one directory per library you just have to remove the `dune` file at the root of `lib` and create one for each subdirectories:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── cli.ml
│   └── dune
├── dune-project
├── lib
│   ├── suba
│   │   ├── dune
│   │   └── suba.ml
│   └── subb
│       ├── dune
│       └── subb.ml
```

The only changes are:

`bin/cli.ml`

```ml
let () =
  Suba.a (); (* no more Lib.(...) *)
  Subb.b ()
```

`bin/dune`

```ml
(executable
 (name cli)
 (libraries suba subb)
)
```

`lib/dune` has been removed

`lib/sub{a|b}/dune`

```ml
(library
 (name sub{a|b})
)
```

And in that case, multiple files inside different directories can have the same name.

Comment: Thank you, the limitation is clearer to me now. I guess as compiled language the bin/lib distinction is important, whereas in Python I'm used to "packages" just as namespaces with unlimited nesting. It appears what I want is this feature request https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/1084 ...  For now, instead of a single `Lib` I have made multiple `Myproject_<whatever>` libs in the root of my project dir. That way I can live with the single level of nesting and the naming is not too bad.

Comment: You don't have to put your libs directories outside of your `lib` directory, you just have to create one `dune` file in each `subdirectory` to declare it as its own library. I can edit my answer if that's not clear for you but just try to cut/paste al you library directories inside your `lib` directory and it should work

Comment: Ah that is good to know, it keeps the root dir more tidy that way, thanks 

Comment: apparently `(include_subdirs qualified)` got released in Dune 3.7.0 https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#include-subdirs the docs don't give examples to clarify but I think it does what I originally wanted